# Detect if ArrayList contains multiple instance of the same object

Tags: java, arraylist

I tried to detect if an ArrayList contains the same coppies of an object with no success. Here is my code;

```
public class Foo{
    int id;
    int name;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        Foo f = (Foo)o;
        return f.id==this.id;
    }

}

//in another class
ArrayList<Foo> foos;
...
boolean ifFoosListContainsMultipleFoo(Foo f){
    return foos.indexOf(f)!=foos.lastIndexOf(f);
}
//but this method always returns `false` even the `foos` list
//contains multiple object with the same `id`;
```

So, what am I doing wrong and is there a more optimal way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I saw that I need to override `hash` method of the `Foo` class, then why `equals` function is not enough;

**EDIT 2:** Sorry for wasting your time but it was my mistake. There is no problem with my code, I used `ifFoosListContainsMultipleFoo` as !ifFoosListContainsMultipleFoo so this was result of `false` response.

Apologize me.

Comment: why not using foos.contains(object) ???

Comment: I'm not sure but don't you have to override `hashCode` method as well?

Comment: no I didn't override hashCode

Comment: Agree with @StefanBeike you can use foos.contains() & also you will need to override hashcode method as well.

Comment: Stefan Beike I need to know if the arraylist contains more than one instance of the same object; not if it contains one or not

Comment: @wawek He is using an ArrayList and the implementation of the indexOf method does never use hashCode, only equals.

Comment: ah ok I got it. ok then you need something else

Comment: I've tried your code as is, and it does not compile. Try changing `boolean equals...` to `@Override public equals(Object o)` and see what happens. Another note, with regards to the `hashcode` method, although it is not required in this case, it is considered good practice to amend it when the default equality mechanism is overridden since it can cause problems down the line should sets or maps, for instance, be used.

Comment: @ismail whether you really need to override hashcode or not depends on what kind of collection you are working with. But it's best practice to always implement equals if you implement hashCode, and the other way around too.

Comment: After adding public to the equals method, the code seems to work for me. Can you provide a complete runnable example?

Comment: Thanks I edited it and yes it has a public access modifier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should work as it is, except in the case where `f` is **not** present in the list at all..

So you can do something like,

```
boolean ifFoosListContainsMultipleFoo(Foo f){
    return (foos.indexOf(f) != -1) && (foos.indexOf(f)!=foos.lastIndexOf(f));
}
```

Comment: Maybe store the first `indexOf` in a variable to spare one iteration through the list.

Comment: Both methods will return -1 if the element is not present, so I think this is unnecessary.

Comment: In this state if the element is present the first index is computed twice.

Comment: ohh @WilQu I didn't look it carefully but you are right in this query there is no need to check if list contains the element.

Comment: @WilQu, yes... you are right... I am wondering why it's not working for the OP in that case...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`HashSet<Foo>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) to do this. You should override `hashCode` as well because `HashSet` uses hashes internally.

```
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<Foo>(foos);
// check for duplicates
set.size() == foos.size();
```

You can also use the set manually which should let you retain the duplicates and can let you end the check sooner (instead of adding everything):

```
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<Foo>();
// check for duplicates
for (Foo foo : foos){
    if (!set.contains(foo)){
        set.add(foo);
    } else {
        // do something with foo, which is a duplicate.
        // possibly end check for duplicates or store in a list
    }
}
```